# Avoid matrix multiplication in algebraic multigrid method

Tags: linear-algebra, performance, multigrid

Currently when I try to solve a linear algebra system of the form of $A x =b$ I use the algebraic multigrid method. The algebraic multigrid method uses a Galerkin product to form the coarse grid matrix ($A_c = RA_fP$). Where $R$ is the restriction operator, $P$ the prolongation operator, $A_c$ the coarse grid matrix and $A_f$ the fine grid matrix.

In the current state of my implementation I perform the matrix multiplication to form the coarse grid. This step is quite expensive and I was asking myself if there is a way to use the restriction and prolongation operators directly in combination with the fine grid matrix instead of calculating the coarse grid matrix.

The first problem I was facing is to form the strong connection matrix from the fine grid matrix $A_f$, the restriction operator $R$ and the prolongation operator $P$.

Is there any available algebraic multigrid package that is not calculating the coarse grid matrix but using the operators?

Comment: You can just do: $vu =A_c v = (RA_fP)v = R(A_f(Pv))$, which would perform the multiplication $v' = Pv$ in the first step, then $v'' = A_fv'$, and finally $u = Rv''$. This avoids computing $RA_fP$ but requires extra prolongation and restriction computations.